# Shut down syspro 7 processes

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, automation, batch

We have nightly backups run on our Windows Server 2012 R2 sys pro 7 server. Having the syspro processes running during backups can cause file lock issues and other errors. Does anyone know a way we could  automatically shut down our syspro 7 processes prior to doing our backups and then start them up again after the backup completes? By the way we are using a C-ISAM database not SQL Server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a batch file stopping all the relevant services and use Task Scheduler to run this before your backup. Then create another batch file to start all the services up and schedule this for when the backup is complete. For your task ensure that you set it to run with elevated privileges or the services will not be stopped/started.

For example, assuming you are using the SYSPRO Communications Service, you would stop this using the following command in your batch file:`net stop SYSPROCOMMS`
Do this for each of your services you want to stop.

After you have stopped your services it would probably be worthwhile killing any runaway processes that might exist (e.g. **SYSPRO.exe** or **SYSPROSrs.exe**). You could make use of [Sysinternal's PSKILL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx) to do this for you in your batch file.

You can check out the [SYSPRO Forums](http://forums.syspro.com/) for help relating to [syspro](/questions/tagged/syspro).